# 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledbexception

i keep getting this error whenever i run this code and i really cant find what im missing here so please help me thanks in advance

the error:
'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

the front end code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFunction" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"
    DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />


                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="FunctionDate" HeaderText="Function Date" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="FunctionTime" HeaderText="Function Time" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="CelebrateName" HeaderText="Celebrate Name" />


                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="FunctionDate" HeaderText="Function Date" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="CelebrateName" HeaderText="Celebrate Name" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Back end code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;

namespace mntfinal
{
   public partial class editreport : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            gvFunction.DataSource = GetData("select ID, 
            FunctionDate, CelebrateName from function");
            gvFunction.DataBind();
        }
    }
    private static DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
         ["MandapamDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                using (OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string ID = gvFunction.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            GridView gvOrders = e.Row.FindControl("gvOrders") as GridView;
            gvOrders.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select ID,FunctionDate,FunctionTime,CelebrateName from function where ID='{0}'", ID));
            gvOrders.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The criteria expression is the part of the query containing the
>   conditions, as in WHERE .

The problem seems to be with your where clause, you are trying to compare the ID column value(which might be an integer) with a string.
Try this, I have **removed the single quotes** around {0}:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string ID = gvFunction.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            GridView gvOrders = e.Row.FindControl("gvOrders") as GridView;
            gvOrders.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select ID,FunctionDate,FunctionTime,CelebrateName from function where ID={0}", ID));
            gvOrders.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your ID field an int or a string field? Try changing the string to an int, and remove the quotes around {0}.

Comment: its on auto number and i guess its an int? if it is can you please tell me me how i can replace value.Tostring()? cuz im quite an amateur

Comment: Try the code provided by @sachin first, i guess that's enough.

Answer (score 0):

a very rough guess is, that string ID contains something strange.. e.g. "null"

check what 
    string.Format("select ID,FunctionDate,FunctionTime,CelebrateName from function where ID='{0}'", ID)
looks like and post the final sql statement here, i guess we can see the cause here.